# Where is the distinction made from measurable functions to measurable sets?

Tags: measure-theory

I was following a particular proof in Measure Theory, one which proves that the function $\{x\in X: f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ is measurable. For completion's sake, here it is.

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let f and g be measurable functions from X into $[-\infty,+\infty]$. Then the set $\{x\in X: f(x)\neq g(x)\}$ is measurable.

The problem in the proof is in the following line...

---

$$\{x \in X: f(x) \neq g(x)\}=\{x \in X: f(x)<g(x) \}\cup \{x \in X:g(x)<f(x)\}$$

Since $\{x \in X: f(x)<g(x) \}$ and $\{x \in X:g(x)<f(x)\}$ are **both measurable** then $\{x \in X: f(x)<g(x)\}$ is **measurable.**

---

The first time I went through this I initially had no problem with that statement. Only after did I question the fact that I have no idea what a measurable set IS when it isn't of the form $\{x \in X : h(x)>0 \}$. After all we begin with the definition of measurable functions and later on we can show that:

A function $f$ is measurable iff $\{x: f(x)>a\}\in \mathcal{A}, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ (and similar of the sort)

So I suppose my question is...how to we interpret the measurability of $\{x \in X: f(x) \neq g(x) \}$ when there we can't use the theorems mentioned to link it back to measurable sets of the form we know? Or is there and I'm just not seeing it ?

Comment: I'm confused. $\{x\in X: f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ is not a function, it's a set. Besides, in the last line before the horizontal line, isn't it supposed to beb $\{x\in X: f(x) \neq g(x)\}$? I'm pretty sure that in this context "is a measurable set" means "$\in \mathcal A$". But I don't really understand your question.

Comment: The material i'm reviewing constantly uses the language in this section
"Because the set can be expressed as a union of measurable sets, then it is measurable"...

So I've lost the distinction myself...

Comment: @tomasz 
Would a measurable set mean $\in \mathcal{A}$?
Because in that case problem is solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we have a fixed set $X$ with a ($\sigma-$)algebra of sets $\mathcal A$, it is the more or less universal (as far as I can tell) convention that a measurable subset of $X$ is just one that is in $\mathcal A$.

Things can be more ambiguous when there is a measure involved, because that gives you the notion of a set measurable in the sense of Carathéodory, but this is not the case here.

Even more universally, a measurable function is one such that preimages of measurable sets are measurable. Thus if $f\colon X\to {\bf R}$ is measurable (which usually means that it is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of ${\bf R}$), certainly $\{x\in X\mid f(x)<a\}$ is measurable, but it is just an example of a measurable set, not a definition.

Comment: I think your comment and this answer nails the ambiguity. At this point in time I have only been familiarized with the word 'measurable' being used for functions and subsequently, a function $f$ being measurable iff $\{x : f(x)<a\}\in \mathcal{A}$.

I was not familiarized with the convention that 'measurable' subsets of $X$ are those in $\mathcal{A}$.

Thank you!

Comment: When considering functions from $(X, \mathcal A)$ to $\mathbb R$, you want to use the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$, **not** the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets.  The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the sets $(-\infty, a)$, so any function $f$ such that $\{x \in X \mid f(x) < a\}$ is measurable for all $a \in \mathbb R$ is a measurable function.  It is not true that $\{x \in X \mid f(x) \in B\}$ is measurable for every Lebesgue measurable $B$, even if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yes, that's correct. I've written a paragraph that in case of topological measure spaces, "measurable" usually means "Borel" or "Baire", but decided against including it in favour of brevity.

Answer (score 2):

The assertion that the set $\{ x\in X: f(x) < g(x)\}$ is measurable is not obvious and requires proof. You argue this way:
$$
\begin{align}
\{x\in X:f(x) < g(x)\}
 &= \bigcup_{r\in{\mathbb Q}}\{ x\in X: f(x) < r < g(x)\}\\
 &= \bigcup_{r\in{\mathbb Q}}\left(\{ x\in X: f(x) < r\}\cap\{x\in X: g(x) > r \}\right)
\end{align}
$$
The reasoning is that if one real number is less than another, then you can squeeze a rational in between them (and conversely). The final expression is a countable union of measurable sets, since $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions.

Comment: Yes but the question was not related to that, it is asking why $\{x \in X: f(x) \neq g(x) \}$ is being called 'measurable' in the first place.

Comment: @Malcolm The proof that you wrote down is demonstrating that the *set* $\{x\in X: f(x)\ne g(x)\}$ is measurable. To prove it's measurable you first write it as a union of two other sets, which you argue are measurable.

Comment: @Malcolm To answer your question "Would a measurable set mean $\in\cal A$"? Yes, a set is measurable means it belongs to the sigma-algebra.

Comment: I understand that, but up till this point in time I had only been introduced to measurable functions. Later on, showed that $f$ is measurable iff $\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\} \in \mathcal{A}$. 

Then all of a sudden 'measurable' started being used for sets. Which completely didn't make sense. But the distinction has been cleared. Thank you for your response regardless :)